# Calling jQuery Plugin on click

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have searched and searched but have not found a simple answer to why the following does not work. What I was trying to do is call a jQuery plugin in a click event instead of at page load (doc ready). So, this code works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#slidingtabs").slidingTabs({ 
                tabActive:1, 
                totalHeight:"580", 
                orientation:"vertical" 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This code below does not work. I have put the same code inside a click function. I get no errors, but nothing happens:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#testbutton2").click(function(){
                $("#slidingtabs").slidingTabs({ 
                tabActive:1, 
                totalHeight:"380", 
                orientation:"vertical"  
            });

                });
        });
    </script>
```

Can someone tell me why it doesn't work, and what I need to do to call the plugin on a click event, or a re-size window event, or equivalent?

Could this be something specific to this plugin (I did not write it)?

Thank you for any help or insight.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing some of the HTML in your question would help.
I would start using chrome dev tools or firebug in firefox and run:

```
$("#testbutton2").length
```

to verify you are selecting something.

Then add a console.log inside your click handler to make sure that something is happenning.

Comment: I will try that. But is there something about putting it in a click event that would make this not work? As I said it works fine outside of the click event.

Comment: I have not used slidingTabs, but if works on page load then you could try initializing the slidingTabs on page load and then making that div visible on click using the 'display' style or using one of the jQuery .show() method.

Comment: This will not achieve what I am looking for. Can someone please let me know if what I have there (calling the plugin on a click event) is possible to do? Does it have to do with how the plugin is written (can a plugin be written to only work on doc ready)? I really don't understand why this wouldn't work, and hours or searching has led to no answers. If someone could even just tell me why this doesn't work, that would be helpful. Thank you!